# Dexie: How to handle removing non-indexed props from database?

Tags: indexeddb, dexie

Say I have the following schema for indexed values: `db.version(1).stores({friends: "++id,name"});`

In addition, my friend object has a non-indexed prop called `phoneNumber`, so in IndexedDB each row has `id, name, phoneNumber`.

If I decide later that `phoneNumber` is no-longer needed, what is the proper way of removing `phoneNumber` from the existing rows? Should it be done within the `upgrade` method?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about dexie, but speaking generally, I would not use the upgrade method to perform this change. Upgrading the database is generally reserved for schema changes. Changing a non-indexed, non-key property is not a schema change.

The proper way to remove the phoneNumber property is to iterate over all friends in the friend object store, read each friend object, delete the phoneNumber property, then write the friend object back to the store.

You could make this change a function, and add it to a set of migration function calls by upgrade, but this is merely subjective. I would only recommend doing that if your app is coded such that you needed to change the database version to do this. But here it sounds more like this is a version change of your application itself. This doesn't affect the version of your database. So this should be tied into a migratory function of your app version change handler.